# Change windows WIN+D shortcut

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to reassing WIN+D to CTRL+ALT+D.
Is it possible via registry or any automatic tool @ startup?

I tried with autohotkey `#d::^!a` in windows 10 but it doesn't work!

Comment: I would try following the instructions over at https://www.maketecheasier.com/change-default-keyboard-shortcuts-windows10/

Comment: Thanks, already tried. #d::^!a autohotkey doesn't work in windows 10!

Comment: Can you edit the question to show your autohotkey script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely do this using [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys), a set of utilities developed by Microsoft itself.
In particular, you may want to take a look at [Keyboard Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager) which allows you to remap keys or shortcuts.
You can find detailed and easy to follow instructions on shortcut remapping in the [Remap Shortcuts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager#remap-shortcuts) section.

Comment: Did it! I had tried before posting, but the menu to remap the shortcuts was not clear to me. I tried again an got it. Thanks!

Comment: Just in case - PowerToys still require background process to work, though they don't  give 10 VirusTotal warnings like old AutoHotkey versions. Win+1..9+Python - no background process, no desktop Ctrl+Alt+* seconds delay, extra flexibility for fast modification.